# Single v Multiple REST endpoint

Tags: rest, endpoint

Were working on making legacy code (Java) accessible via a REST API (Java/Spring/JSON).

Essentially our legacy code has numerous command processor type classes (which take in commands) and serve data back to the caller. So we have numerous command processors with numerous methods in them. Each method is analogous to a GET/POST of data, i.e. getCustomer / getCustomers / addCustomer etc..

We discussed 2 options:

- **Option 1** - Create endpoints for every operation.
- **Option 2** - Create one single REST endpoint and pass in a generic payload. The JSON being passed in would have a "type" identifier which in the endpoint we could then "construct" the require object type

I think option #1 is a better design as it's much simpler and adheres more to REST. I don't like option #2 as the single endpoint is now actually like a fancy front controller or dispatcher and would then either contain a huge switch statement.

I'd be interested in seeing what you guys think, pros / cons.

Comment: In fact, Option 2 isn't RESTful at all.

For your case, you should have a /customers endpoint, where you can GET to retrieve the list of all customers (you can filter if you want using query params), POST a new customer which will be available at /customers/{newCustomerId}, then GET /customers/123 to get the customer with id 123 etc.

I suggest this [reading](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api).

Comment: As said above, option 2 has nothing to do with REST. But even option 2 is not RESTful *unless* you think about what your *resources* are. REST is not about commands or operations, that's the old RPC way. REST is about resources.

Comment: If you really wants a REST API, then **all the four levels** described [here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) must be implemented.

Comment: @LutzHorn REST is just as old as RPC -- they're just different and each is useful in its own way where appropriate according to the needs of the system under development.

Comment: @sp00m That's a bit strong -- REST is a style, not a standard, and you can implement REST and still be in strict violation of that particular maturity-model (which is actually an http maturity model, not a rest maturity model because it doesn't actually reference any of Fielding's original concepts). Rest doesn't even have to be on HTTP (http://www.gridshore.nl/2010/08/16/yes-rest-really-is-not-the-same-as-http/)